What is the actual timepoint SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE generated for tcp bytestream data?
I'm learning how to use the SO_TIMESTAMPING option to get timestamps for measuring the latency of my application, which uses TCP to transfer data. The NIC of my test server supports SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE, so I managed to use the SO_TIMESTAMPING socket option with SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE and recvmsg to get the timestamps. Everything seemed to work fine initially.
However, when I performed the test below, I discovered that the timestamp is not actually the time when the bytes were received by the NIC.
TEST

TCP server accepts incoming client connections and writes 20B of data 20 times, sleeping for 1 second after each write. TCP_NODELAY is set for the server socket.
TCP client sleeps for 20 seconds after connecting to the server (i.e., until the server finishes writing), and then calls recvmsg with a buffer size of 20B, so it will call recvmsg 20 times and get 20 RX timestamps.

Since the server enables TCP_NODELAY, I expect each server write to generate a packet with 20B TCP payload immediately, and the client to receive this packet and timestamp it whenever the packet arrives, even though the client is sleeping and not calling recvmsg yet. Using tcpdump on the client side, the output shows that the packets are indeed received one by one, each second.
However, my test shows that all 20 recvmsg calls have the same RX timestamp, which is the time of the last packet.
Output (read index, RX timestamp, Payload with send timestamp in it):
# all RX timestamp is 1729223045.596191883, and the last packet was sent at 1729223045.596149
# server and client's sysclock is almost synced, network RTT < 100us

0 1729223045.596191883 1729223026.594545...
1 1729223045.596191883 1729223027.594635...
2 1729223045.596191883 1729223028.594719...
3 1729223045.596191883 1729223029.594802...
4 1729223045.596191883 1729223030.594888...
5 1729223045.596191883 1729223031.594971...
6 1729223045.596191883 1729223032.595056...
7 1729223045.596191883 1729223033.595140...
8 1729223045.596191883 1729223034.595223...
9 1729223045.596191883 1729223035.595306...
10 1729223045.596191883 1729223036.595391...
11 1729223045.596191883 1729223037.595475...
12 1729223045.596191883 1729223038.595559...
13 1729223045.596191883 1729223039.595647...
14 1729223045.596191883 1729223040.595731...
15 1729223045.596191883 1729223041.595813...
16 1729223045.596191883 1729223042.595899...
17 1729223045.596191883 1729223043.595981...
18 1729223045.596191883 1729223044.596067...
19 1729223045.596191883 1729223045.596149...

I'm using Kernel 4.14.252-195.483.amzn2.x86_64.
I read the kernel documentation on timestamping
It describes SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE as:

Request rx timestamps when data enters the kernel. These timestamps are generated just after a device driver hands a packet to the kernel receive stack.

Shouldn't each 20B packet be "handed to the kernel" right afer it arrives at the NIC?
If I change the client code to recv all data without sleep, the RX timestamps are normal.
